# OOZIE status check throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, oozie, bigdata

I am new to oozie,  trying to write a oozie workflow in `CDH4.1.1`. So I started the oozie service and then I checked the status using this command:

`sudo service oozie status`

I got the message:

`running`

Then I tried this command for checking the status:

`oozie admin --oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie status`

And I got the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.AuthOozieClient.writeAuthToken(AuthOozieClient.java:182)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.AuthOozieClient.createConnection(AuthOozieClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.validateWSVersion(OozieClient.java:243)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.createURL(OozieClient.java:344)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.access$000(OozieClient.java:76)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient$ClientCallable.call(OozieClient.java:410)
    at org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient.getSystemMode(OozieClient.java:1299)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.adminCommand(OozieCLI.java:1323)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:499)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:466)
    at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:176)
null
```

Reading the exception stack, I am unable to figure out the reason for this exception. Please let me know why I got this exception and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the env property `USE_AUTH_TOKEN_CACHE_SYS_PROP` in your cluster. As per your stacktrace and the [code](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/client/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/oozie/client/AuthOozieClient.html#line.104) .

Usually the clusters are setup with Kerberos based authentication, which is set up by following the steps [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_sg_oozie_security.html) . Not sure if you want to do that, but just wanted to mentioned that as an FYI.

Comment: as per the code, this is an environmental variable that oozie client checks before proceeding to use the auth token that it acquires. Since you are not passing any `-auth ` param to the oozie call, it would be null I guess. can you check if your oozie script (`which oozie`) is picking any env variables from?

Comment: `which oozie` gives me this path: `/usr/bin/oozie` This is a shell script, it detects the java_home and then executes this line: `exec /usr/lib/oozie/bin/oozie "$@"` can you please suggest what to do?

Comment: was checking other sources and bumped into https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1010. Can you check if the version that you are using is not this? Also, can you try passing `-auth SIMPLE` to your command as indicated in the ticket?

Comment: will check the version. where to pass this param: `-auth SIMPLE` in the oozie call? Which command of oozie should incorporate this `-auth` param?

Comment: can you try `oozie admin --oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie status -auth SIMPLE`  ?

Comment: I tried but nothing happens i.e. no error, no message is displayed. The oozie version i am using is: `Oozie client build version: 3.2.0-cdh4.1.1`

Comment: That is strange. Can you check your oozie logs to see if there was an error after the latest run? Also, can you check  if `curl -m 10 http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/admin/status`  returns anything?

Comment: `curl -m 10 http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/admin/status` gives me `{"systemMode":"NORMAL"}`

Comment: As per https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/WebServicesAPI.html#System_Status , the status seems to be consistent.

Comment: But when i try to runt he job using: `oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run` then i get the same `NullPointerException`. Please comment.

Comment: do you see the same issue inspite of passing `-auth SIMPLE` ?

Comment: oh i got it now: if i use this command: `oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -auth SIMPLE -run` then the workflow is getting submitted successfully.

Comment: is there some way to fix is permanently without passing `-auth` everytime?

Comment: not sure why you are seeing this problem. Can you try `sudo -u oozie oozie admin -status -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie` ? the `-auth SIMPLE` based command was supposed to create a `.oozie-auth-token` file in your home dir. Which on subsequent runs, shouldnt be necessary. Can you check if you can see the file?

Comment: `sudo -u oozie oozie admin -status -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie` give me the same null pointer excepiton

Comment: And moreover, to enable the simple auth, i have already modified the `core-site.xml` with `hadoop.security.authentication` as `simple` and `hadoop.security.authorization` as `false` and then I restarted all the jobtracker, tasktracker, namenode and datanode.

Comment: I can see the file `-rw--w---- 1 training training 79 Mar  1 21:53 .oozie-auth-token` in user home directory